# Error in installing pygame-sdl2 dependencies on ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, pygame, sdl-2

Whem I run the following command on my ubuntu terminal for pygame_sdl2

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev libsdl2-dev libsdl2-image-dev libsdl2-mixer-dev libsdl2-ttf-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev virtualenvwrapper --fix-missing
```

I get error:

```
Err:1 http:// fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 libpcrecpp0v5 amd64 2:8.39-3
  404  Not Found [IP: 194.158.119.186 80]
Err:2 http:// fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main amd64 libudev-dev amd64 232-21ubuntu3
  404  Not Found [IP: 194.158.119.186 80]
Err:3 http:// fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 libdbus-1-dev amd64 1.10.10-1ubuntu2

Err:12 http:// fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 libmircookie-dev amd64 0.26.2+17.04.20170322.1-0ubuntu2


Err:19 http:// fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 libpcre32-3 amd64 2:8.39-3

E: Failed to fetch http:// fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/stevedore/python-stevedore_1.20.0-0ubuntu2_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 194.158.119.186 80]
E: Aborting install.
```

Someone please help me:(

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Zesty (17.04) doesn't have Long Term Support, which means it just have a 9-month support, [until January, 2018](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ZestyZapus/ReleaseNotes).

Now this version of Ubuntu has been end of life, please upgrade to Bionic (18.04 LTS) or downgrade to Xenial (16.04 LTS).

If you still want to use this version of Ubuntu, please change the source (that is, replace the content `/etc/apt/sources.list` with [Old Releases](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/) `http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/`).