# Not able to sudo apt-get update

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get

I get error when I run `sudo apt-get update`

Reading package lists... Done
E: Method mirror has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process mirror received a segmentation fault.

Comment: What OS are you running? Do you have any custom lines/files in your source lists?

Comment: you can see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54999153/11054103

Comment: It now worked! I had edited some other lines from another source prior to this which now I have commented